# DateTime.ToString formatting

Tags: c#, datetime, localization, formatting

I'm displaying localized short dates by providing culture info to `DateTime.ToString` method. By now I was using

```
x.ToString("d", ci); // 23.12.2000
```

that displays short date. But now I would like to also include abbreviated day name. I tried

```
x.ToString("ddd d", ci); // pon 23
```

but now `d` becomes day specifier instead of short date format so instead of day name and short date I only get day name and day number.

**How do I convince formatter to display day along with predefined culture short date format?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
string.Format(ci, "{0:ddd} {0:d}", x)
```

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't work as that would return, to cite Robert "pon 23" instead of "pon 23.12.2000"

Comment: @Manatherin, no, that would have exactly the same problem as the example in the original question. I prefer my approach, but Kristoffer's solves the problem succinctly too.

Comment: Ah good point, read the post wrong and though that was what he wanted not what he was getting at the moment

Comment: Thanks @Kristoffer. This is rather clever. I don't know why I haven't thought of it myself.

Answer (score 4):

The "standard" formatting strings work by obtaining the equivalent property of the `CultureInfo`'s `DateTimeFormat`. In this case `"d"` finds the `ShortDatePattern` property, which will be something like "dd.MM.yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" and so on, depending on that locale in question.

Hence you can make use of it in a custom pattern like so:

```
x.ToString("ddd " + ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, ci) // Sat 2000-12-23 on my set up, should presumably be pon 23.12.2000 on yours
```

Comment: +1 Totally taught me something new there. I would have used String.Format. Nice to learn the alternatives.

Comment: String.Format as per @Kristoffer Jansson's answer is a fine way to skin the same cat too, though the above can be the only way to deal with some more complicated cases where you want to pass the string from one place to a ToString() call in another (and hence can't change from ToString() to String.Format()). And yes, it *is* nice to know how the standard formats work too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
x.ToString("ddd ", ci) + x.ToString("d", ci);
```

Comment: Yeah. This is what I've done before I got a great answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this explanation:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Maybe you can find some examples there.

**Update**

As response to the comment, Example 3 in the first codeblock clearly states how to do this:

```
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
```

Googling a question about date to string formatting, and hitting this question will be much more valuable if there is a reference to good examples. Hence the reference to the csharp-examples site.

Comment: Also copying/pasting from the first result of google is not convenient. Don't think it deserved a downvote for that. The answer is not incorrect, or misses the questions.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, the question is how to display "ddd" followed by the full short date in culture specific format. Your code sample does not do this.

Comment: The updated answer gives a completely wrong answer. It's even commented with an example output that is clearly wrong. Not a single example in the link given answers the question either. The answer is both incorrect AND misses the question.

Comment: My apologies.. I was missing the point slightly. Sorry for being a bit triggerhappy here.

Comment: As others mentioned already. I know I can format dates manually, but that's not what I wanted to do. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you could: `x.ToString("ddd", ci) + " " + x.ToString("d", ci)`;